# Setting value of a parameter in html by calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

Is there a way to do this?
    <'param name = "ticket" value = "getTicket()">

`getTicket()` is my Javascript function. Whatever the function returns, that should be the value of the parameter tag.

I cant set it explicitly using Javascript `"document.getElem...."` because I want the value to be loaded at the time of page load. Or, while the parameter is being set.

For further info, I am trying to do this for **Tableau Trusted Authentication**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using server-side scripting?

Isn't more effectively to do what you do using the request/response ways?

Like directly using `<%=ticketValue%>` (ASP way) or `${ticketValue}` (JSP way)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Document.Write as follows:

```
<'param name = "ticket" value = "<script>
document.write(getTicket());
</script>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access node from JavaScript right after it was created.
You're not obligated to wait for `DOMContentLoaded` event. So this code will work as expected:

```
<script>
  function getTicket() {
    return 'whatever';
  }
</script>

<param name="ticket" value="" class="js-ticket">
<script>
  var ticket = document.querySelector('.js-ticket');
  ticket.value = getTicket();

  console.log(ticket);
</script>
```

[See demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mlrdb).

This approach is better than using `document.write`, see good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery $(document).ready() function callback. If jquery isn't available, then you can use the equivalence of it.

[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Then you can access document.getElement.